# Enabling a button after it has been disabled

Tags: vb.net

I am making a program to take orders from a customer, the user of the program cannot add more than 10 of any item to the listview. So I made a counter to increment every time they pressed the button, and every time they would press the delete button it would take away one from the counter. The problem is when the user presses the save button and then deletes that order, the button does not enable again.

```
    Private Sub drinkSavebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drinkSavebtn.Click

        colaCounter.Maximum = 10
        cola = drinkOutput.Items.Add("Cola") 'prints the name of the beverage to the list view
        cola.SubItems.Add(colaCounter.Value.ToString) 'the amount of beverages orders are added through a sub item and converted to a string

        LemonadeCounter.Maximum = 10
        lemonade = drinkOutput.Items.Add("Lemonade")
        lemonade.SubItems.Add(LemonadeCounter.Value.ToString)

        waterCounter.Maximum = 10 'sets the maximum amount of drinks you can order
        water = drinkOutput.Items.Add("Water")
        water.SubItems.Add(waterCounter.Value.ToString)

        fizzyOrangeCounter.Maximum = 10
        fizzyOrange = drinkOutput.Items.Add("Fizzy Orange")
        fizzyOrange.SubItems.Add(fizzyOrangeCounter.Value.ToString)


        drinkSaveBtnCounter += 1

        If drinkSaveBtnCounter = 0 Then
            drinkSavebtn.Enabled = True

        ElseIf drinkSaveBtnCounter = 1 Then 'stops the user from being able to enter more than 10 of one drink
            drinkSavebtn.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub drinkDeleteBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drinkDeleteBtn.Click
        drinkOutput.Items.Clear() 'clears the items of a table, leaving the columns intact
        drinkSaveBtnCounter -= 1
    End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't you just enable on delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding **drinkSavebtn.Enabled = True** after resetting your counter in drinkDeleteBtn_Click-method

```
Private Sub drinkDeleteBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drinkDeleteBtn.Click
    drinkOutput.Items.Clear() 'clears the items of a table, leaving the columns intact
    drinkSaveBtnCounter -= 1
    drinkSavebtn.Enabled = True
End Sub
```